# No Touch feedback after changing Button background color in Android

Tags: android

I am using Android API 21 with Android Studio.

I changed the background color of a button. It stopped giving the touch feedback as it was giving earlier.

I was looking for the solution and found ways to create `drawables`, however I read about touch feedback on android's developer website and I found these:

> > https://developer.android.com/design/style/touch-feedback.html
> >
> > Incorporating your branding is much easier because the default touch feedback works with whatever hue you choose.

and

> > https://developer.android.com/design/style/branding.html
> >
> > When customizing colors, touch feedback should be subtle — just slightly lighter or darker than the untouched color.

Does that mean, touch feedback would work even if I changed the background, automatically? Or do I need to do some work to get it working?

Also, If I need to reproduce the feedback manually, how would I do so (any better method than drawables in latest Android Studio)?

Just starting out with android, so pretty confused. Appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the touch feedback (button *pressed* state) explicitly in a drawable. Changing the background would mean loosing the feedback (i.e pressed) state.

The only way to switch Button backgrounds, with its feedback/pressed state, is to define the various Button definitions in Drawables. This will make it easy to switch the backgrounds with just one reference for all the states of the button (disabled, pressed, focused and enabled).

The method setBackgroundResource() sets only the referenced Resource to **all** the states of the Button. So, it's better to define a Button definition, with all its states explicitly, in a Drawable and use those to switch. The same is for setBackgroundColor(), which applies the background color overwriting all the states of the button, and should be used only when required (for most general cases it should not be used).

I do not use Android Studio. I use the old school Eclipse based ADT but, I'm sure there is no workaround for not using Drawables, for button states and backgrounds as Android App development is standardized over the various IDEs.

It's pretty easy to implement the Button definitions via drawables here's a sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- Button Disabled -->
<item
    android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#F4F4F4"
            android:centerColor="#A6A6A6"
            android:endColor="#F4F4F4"
            android:angle="90"/>
        <padding android:left="7dp"
            android:top="7dp"
            android:right="7dp"
            android:bottom="7dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dip"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
    </shape> 
</item>

<!-- Button Pressed / Feedback -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#2222EE"
            android:centerColor="#22EE11"
            android:endColor="#2222EE"
            android:angle="90"/>
        <padding android:left="7dp"
            android:top="7dp"
            android:right="7dp"
            android:bottom="7dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dip"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
    </shape> 
</item>

<!-- Button Focused -->
<!-- Sometimes developers define Shapes in a separate drawable. The code is the same. Here's an example. -->
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"> <!-- Refers to another drawable file with name "button_focused" -->
</item>

<!-- Button Enabled -->
<item
    android:state_enabled="true">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#22EE11"
            android:centerColor="#2222EE"
            android:endColor="#22EE11"
            android:angle="90"/>
        <padding android:left="7dp"
            android:top="7dp"
            android:right="7dp"
            android:bottom="7dp" />
        <stroke
            android:width="2dip"
            android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners android:radius= "8dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

Splitting your Button definitions into more than one drawable has it's pros and cons. It's better to keep one Button definition in one drawable.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

**THE SIMPLEST** solution to this problem is
instead of

```
android:background="@color/myColor"
```

use this line

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/myColor"
```